# The meaning of "heavy-topped and none too sound hocks"

Tags: meaning

The meaning of "heavy-topped and none too sound hocks"

> ‘By Jove! How well you look!’ he cried, without salutation. ‘I didn’t know you rode.’
>
> ‘I used to once,’ she replied. ‘I’m all soft now.’
>
> They swept off together down the ride.
>
> ‘Your beast pulls,’ he said.
>
> ‘Wa-ant him to. Gi-gives me something to think of. How’ve you been?’ she panted. ‘I wish chemists’ shops hadn’t red lights.’
>
> ‘Have you slipped out and bought some, then?’
>
> ‘You don’t know Nursey. Eh, but it’s good to be on a horse again! This chap cost me two hundred.’
>
> ‘Then you’ve been swindled,’ said Conroy.
>
> ‘I know it, but it’s no odds. I must go back to Toots and send him away. He’s neglecting his work for me.’
>
> **She swung her heavy-topped animal on his none too sound hocks.** ‘’Sentence come, lad?’

This is from "In the Same Boat " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/in-the-same-boat.htm

I don't understand the meaning below---
---
--She swung her heavy-topped animal on his none too sound hocks.
'heavey-topped' means  big head of the horse?
'none too sound hocks' means  its hind-legs are hurt?

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 6):

First, [hock](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hock) is part of the horse:

> the middle joint in the back leg of an animal such as a horse

"None too sound" means that the joint is weak.  This might stem from an injury but might just be a problem with the horse from birth

This [betting site](https://dailypunt.com/conformation-and-ground/) explains the conformation:

> Finally, the overall build of the horse can lend itself to favouring certain ground conditions over others. Big, heavy-topped horses who are naturally quite burly or powerfully-built through the shoulder are likely to hit the ground hard when they gallop.

A heavy-topped horse is one that has a lot of muscle in its body, on top of the legs.

Comment: Thank you Marry, I appreciate your kind and detailed answer! It is so helpful.

Comment: More simply, *She turned her big shouldered, weak-legged horse [around].*